# Running a dotnet applicaiton in linux using docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a simple application, basically it is the default application that comes out of the box when you create an asp net project the only thing I've added is swagger. so in the Properties>launchsettings.json I've set the launch URL to point to swagger ui.

I just want to run it on a linux container and be able to access it on my windows host.

I'm running on a windows 10 using docker for windows with a linux containers setting.

So following are the steps

create a release version

```
   dotnet publish --configuration Release -o dist .\myApi.csproj (tried using the .sln file as well)
```

run the container

```
   docker run --rm -it -v pathTo_dis:/usr/app --name aspApp mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest
```

Inside the container I'm running the published app

```
 dotnet /usr/app/myApi.dll
```

I'm getting the

> Now listening on : http://[::]:80

In another powershell I'm inspecting the container for the IPAddress this is it 172.17.0.3 and when I enter the Ip in the browser I get

> The site can't be reached

If i try an access the site using localhost:5003

> This localhost page can’t be found

So, how can you run a .net core app, in a linux container and have access to it ?

Comment: Your `docker run` doesn't include the port mapping argument specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.0#run-in-a-linux-container), any specific reason you don't need to do that here?

Comment: I'm using `publish single file` to ge rid of the dotnet installation in the image. I'm using a default image. `dotnet publish -r linux-arm -c Release /property:PublishSingleFile=true /property:PublishTrimmed=true`

Comment: From the last line of info log (your attached image) `Request finished in 53.2618ms 404`, your request reached to the container and means first problem is resolved. Try use `-p 80:80` (mapping same port) and access `http://localhost/`. If you see same 404 error, that would be a problem on application. otherwise your application does not allow access from mapping port (like reverse proxy). that is also a problem on application setting (routing, security...), not container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need use port option to allow access from outside container.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -v pathTo_dis:/usr/app --name aspApp mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest
```

then you can access `http://localhost:8000`

note:
`8000:80` first number(8000) is host port and second one(80) is container port.